# Validate that a value is in a certain range, e.g. 1 <= val <=2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to validate a number `:value` to be within 1 or 2

```
validates :value, :format => { :with => /1|2/, :message => "Select number.." }
```

However, the above code is failing the validation when `value == 1`

Please ensure that your solution allows me to add a message for the validation.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
validates :value, :inclusion => {:in => [1,2]}
```

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of

Answer (score 18):

You're looking for [validates_inclusion_of](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_inclusion_of):

```
validates_inclusion_of :value, :in => [1, 2],
  :message => "Select one of %{value}"
```

You can also use the (fairly new) shothand form and a Range instead of an Array:

```
validates :value, :inclusion => { :in => 1..2 }
```

Comment: %{value} is the value the user supplied, not the list of allowed options ([1, 2]) like you make it appear. (I'm currently trying to figure out how to interpolate the list of allowed options into the error message myself...)

Comment: BTW, I found the answer (how to interpolate the list of allowed options into the error message) here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8528139/47185 in case anyone's interested

Answer (score 15):

if you want it to be a number within 1 and 2 ( 1.5, 1.6839749, etc ) do

```
validates_numericality_of :value, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1, :less_than_or_equal_to => 2, :message => "blah"
```

may not be what you are looking for but is worth noting,

Comment: Exactly what I needed. No other answers handled decimal cases.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `inclusion` error messages are not good:

```
["Value is not included in the list"]
```

Use

```
validates :value, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 1, less_than_or_equal_to: 10 }
```

For better error messages, like:

```
["Value must be less than or equal to 2"]
```