# custom error message for inclusion validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I am using inclusion validation as

```
validates :field_type, :inclusion => %w(SA LA RB CB SB Date)
```

now when the validation is fired, I am getting `"Field type is not included in the list"`. It is not making any sense to me. So, I want to have my own custom message saying `"This value is not included in Field Type."` Can anyone guide me here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you want:

```
validates :field_type, :inclusion => { :in => %w(SA LA RB CB SB Date),
                                       :message => "The value: %{value} is not included in Field Type." }
```

See [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410275/validate-that-a-value-is-in-a-certain-range-e-g-1-val-2)

Comment: can i add the entered value rather than this value? like if i put "none" can i display error like "none is not included in field type"

Comment: Thanks your solution worked but it was giving "Field type" in front of message, so I edited the message :message => "cannot be %{value}"

Answer (score 1):

Try the message option

```
validates :field_type, :inclusion => %w(SA LA RB CB SB Date), :message => "...."
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#message